# Null Pointer Exception calling method in another class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have a method below in a class called Animals.java

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset()
```

I'm aiming to reuse this within my AnimalInformation.java file, or potentially in the end put it in it's own .java file, but when I did that I still had the same outcome.

To call this I'm using

```
Animals jsonLoader = new Animals();
try {

        JSONArray mainNode = new JSONArray(jsonLoader.loadJSONFromAsset()); // call the connection to json

        if(mainNode != null) //puts the values into an array
        {
            for(int i=0;i<mainNode.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject eachObject = mainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                String location = eachObject.getString("zooLocation");


            }
        }
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So I'm calling the method within the JSONArray, but I think it is here it is causing the null pointer exception.

```
03-04 15:31:52.700    1735-1735/com.myzooo.zoome E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myzooo.zoome, PID: 1735
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myzooo.zoome/com.myzooo.zoome.AnimalInformation}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getAssets(ContextWrapper.java:83)
        at com.myzooo.zoome.Animals.loadJSONFromAsset(Animals.java:177)
        at com.myzooo.zoome.AnimalInformation.onCreate(AnimalInformation.java:28)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I'm a bit lost now because of the way I am trying to use it and I'm not entirely sure if it's the correct way to go about it.
Thanks.

Edit: loadJSONFromAssets() line 177 is InputStream is = getAssets().open("animals.json");

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("animals.json");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

        Log.d("X", "Response Ready:" + stringBuilder.toString());

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: We would need to see `AnimalInformation` and more of the stacktrace to be able to help.

Comment: HAve you created `JSONArray` **constructor** having one parameter **String**?

Comment: `jsonLoader.loadJSONFromAsset()`, can you print it before and see what it is returning?

Comment: Added more of the stacktrace and what there is of AnimalInformation - it's currently not much yet

Comment: Please, post the contents of `loadJSONFromAsset`, and highlight line 177

Comment: @BackSlash added it in

Comment: obviously your `getAssets()` returns `null` value, what's inside?

Comment: getAssets is working when called within the file, it's only when calling it externally it is causing this issue

Comment: @BackSlash I suppose line 177 is `InputStream is = getAssets().open("animals.json");`, so I don't think it's `is`'s problem.

Comment: 'is' is definitely pulling the information, I've just put it within AnimalInformation to double check and it's definitely outputting the JSON info

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here :

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("animals.json");
```

You need a Context to call getAssets() method. You can pass a Context to your loadJSONFromAsset() method and change your code like :

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset(Context ctxt) {

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream is = ctxt.getAssets().open("animals.json");
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

getAssets() gives you a NullPointerException because it returns null. it needs to be called in the Activity Context, so just put it there and call context.getAssets()